# Laplace transformation of piecewise function

Tags: laplace-transform

we have been given the funtion:

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1,  &   0 <x \leq 1 \\
0, &  x > 1
\end{cases}$$
and asked to calculate the Laplace transformation.

I know that with the Heaviside function I can re-write it as 
$$f(x)=1-\mu _1(t)$$

defining $\mu _1$ to be 
$$\mu _1(t)=
\begin{cases}
0,  &   t < 1 \\
1, & t \geq 1
\end{cases}$$

but I don't know where to go after that.

Am I heading in the right direction and how do I continue?

Comment: I say that just computing $$\int_0^1 e^{-st}\,dt$$ is the simplest way.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. Feel a bit silly now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$L[f(t)]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st }dt$$
$$=\int_{0}^{1}e^{-st }dt=\frac{1}{s}\big[-e^s+1\big]$$